# Troubles making a python program to deal cards.

Tags: python

I'm tying to make a card game. What I'm stuck on is dealing the cards. What I've done is make a dict with each card and given it a value because some are worth more than others. What I have in mind is dividing the dictionary into 4 parts, or make 4 copies of each dictionary and then delete 39 cards from each of them (leaving 13 cards for each person). Is this even possible or am I going about this in the wrong way?

```
from random import randint
deck = {}
def makeDeck(deck):
  suit = ['Club', 'Spade', 'Heart', 'Diamond']
  whichSuit = 0
  whichNum = 2
  count = 1
  while count != 52:
    if whichNum == 11:
      whichNum = 'Jack'
    if whichNum == 12:
      whichNum = 'Queen'
    if whichNum == 13:
      whichNum = 'King'
    if whichNum == 14:
      whichNum = 'Ace'
    deck[str(whichNum)+' '+suit[whichSuit]] = count
    count += 1
    if whichNum == 'Jack':
      whichNum = 11
    if whichNum == 'Queen':
      whichNum = 12
    if whichNum == 'King':
      whichNum = 13
    if whichNum == 'Ace':
      whichNum = 14
    whichNum += 1
    if count == 13 or count == 26 or count == 39:
     whichSuit += 1
     whichNum = 2
def dealCards(deck):
  me = deck
  comp1 = deck
  comp2 = deck
  comp2 = deck
```

(Sorry if the code is wrong, this is my first post, Thanks)

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like a great occasion to use classes! I would do it like this:

```
from random import shuffle

class Cards:
    def __init__(self):
        values = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
        suites = ['H', 'S', 'C', 'D']
        self.deck = [j + i for j in values for i in suites]

    def shuffle(self):
        shuffle(self.deck)

    def deal(self, n_players):
        self.hands = [self.deck[i::n_players] for i in range(0, n_players)]

c = Cards()
print c.deck
c.shuffle()
print c.deck
c.deal(4)
print c.hands
```

Comment: Great use of the step value in the slicing

Answer (score 6):

I'm not very experienced with the dictionary functions in Python but what I would do is use card objects and <strike>set</strike> lists with shuffle.

```
from random import shuffle    
class Card:
    def __init__(self,suit,num):
        self.suit = suit
        self.num = num

deck = list()
suits = ['Diamond', 'Heart', 'Spade', 'Club']

nums = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K','A']

for suit in suits: #This is the code that actually makes a deck
    for num in nums:
        deck.append(Card(suit,num))

shuffle(deck)
for number in range(13):
    for player in range(4):
        #deal cards here using deck.pop()
        print(deck.pop().num) #just to prove it works randomly =P
```

I hope that answers your question (because like this is your first question this is my first answer)

Edit: Oops sets is deprecated. Using the built-in set instead.

Edit2: And set.pop() isn't truly random it appears from reading further, just arbitrary. Boy is my face red.

Comment: the "randomness" that you use (order of `Card()` objects inside `set()`) depends on `hash()` implementation that for CPython and user-defined classes by default is `id()` i.e, the address in memory. It is a *very* poor substitute for randomness. You could put the `Card()` objects into an ordinary Python list instead of a `set` and use `random.shuffle()` to shuffle the deck as in [@Benjamin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8469173/4279).

Answer (score 1):

One option for you would be simply to use python's built-in function `random.shuffle`. Don't bother with dictionaries; just create a list of cards and shuffle it whole:

```
>>> import random
>>> ranks = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'K', 'Q']
>>> suits = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']
>>> cards = [[rank, suit] for rank in ranks for suit in suits]
>>> random.shuffle(cards)
>>> cards
[['J', 'S'], ['2', 'S'], ['3', 'S'], ['9', 'S'], ['9', 'D'], ['5', 'S'], 
 ['8', 'H'], ['A', 'C'], ['4', 'D'], ['Q', 'H'], ['2', 'C'], ['Q', 'D'], 
 ['7', 'H'], ['4', 'C'], ['7', 'S'], ['6', 'C'], ['K', 'H'], ['6', 'S'], 
 ['9', 'C'], ['9', 'H'], ['A', 'H'], ['J', 'C'], ['2', 'D'], ['J', 'H'], 
 ['3', 'H'], ['4', 'H'], ['8', 'C'], ['Q', 'S'], ['10', 'S'], ['A', 'S'], 
 ['K', 'S'], ['5', 'D'], ['10', 'D'], ['8', 'D'], ['7', 'C'], ['5', 'C'], 
 ['Q', 'C'], ['3', 'D'], ['8', 'S'], ['6', 'H'], ['A', 'D'], ['2', 'H'], 
 ['6', 'D'], ['K', 'D'], ['10', 'C'], ['5', 'H'], ['4', 'S'], ['K', 'C'], 
 ['7', 'D'], ['10', 'H'], ['3', 'C'], ['J', 'D']]
```

If you need to roll your own, consider the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html). It's super simple.

At the risk of stating the dreadfully obvious, once you have a shuffled list, you can simply deal it by slicing it like so:

```
>>> hand1 = cards[0:13]
>>> hand2 = cards[13:26]
# ...and so on...
```

Or in whatever more complicated way you need. (However, note that there's no need to cycle through the hands or anything like that; since it's already random, simple slicing will suffice.)

Comment: @Benjamin, once the cards are shuffled, dealing is less than trivial. I chose not to insult the OP's intelligence.

Comment: @Benjamin, I doubt that he literally meant that "distributing the deck into hands" was his problem. But I suppose it's possible; edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can `distribute` cards among n players using the [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) library.

**Playing Cards**

```
import itertools as it

import more_itertools as mit


# Build a Deck
suits = "♥♠♣♦"
ranks = list(range(2, 11)) + list("JQKA")
cards = list(it.product(suits, ranks))
print("Number of cards:", len(cards))
# Out: Number of cards: 52

# Shuffle and Distribute
players = 5
random.shuffle(cards)
hands = [list(hand) for hand in list(mit.distribute(players, cards))]
hands[0]                                               # player 1
```

Output

```
[('♥', 'A'),
('♥', 6),
('♦', 9),
('♠', 'A'),
('♥', 7),
('♠', 8),
('♣', 10),
('♦', 'K'),
('♥', 4),
('♠', 4),
('♠', 'Q')]
```

It looks like player 1 has 2 pair.

---

**What is this tool doing?**

[`more_itertools.distribute`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.distribute) equally distributes items from an iterable among n sub-groups.

Modified example from [the docs](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.distribute):

```
>>> n, iterable = 3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> children = distribute(n, iterable)
>>> [list(c) for c in children]
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

`more_itertools` is a third-party package comprising [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) and many other [useful tools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question and problem and checked here. I had to create a program that creates and shuffles the deck and then deals the cards. I have checked all of the examples and the one provided by [Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483620/benjamin) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469043/troubles-making-a-python-program-to-deal-cards/8469173#8469173) was well structured and gave me the base to continue.

I am sharing the completed solution for my exercise here:

#### Code:

```
from random import shuffle

class Cards:
    def __init__(self):
        ranks = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
        suites = ['♥', '♠', '♣', '♦']
        self.deck = [j + i for j in ranks for i in suites]
        self.deal = []

    def shuffle(self):
        shuffle(self.deck)

    def deal_out(self,num_cards, num_players):
        deal = [[0 for x in range(num_cards)] for y in range(num_players)]
        for i in range(num_cards):
            for k in range(num_players):
                deal[k][i]=self.deck.pop()
        self.deal = deal


#declare number of players and cards to be dealt
num_cards = int(input("Please enter a number of cards to be dealt: "))
num_players = int(input("Please enter a number of players: "))

#create new game with new deck
first_game = Cards()
print('\nDeck:\n')
print(first_game.deck)

#shuffle cards
first_game.shuffle()
print('\nShuffled Deck:\n')
print(first_game.deck)

#deal cards
first_game.deal_out(num_cards, num_players)

#Print the dealt cards
print('\nDealt cards:\n')
print(first_game.deal)

#Print cards left after the deal
print('\nCards left in the deck after the deal:\n')
print(first_game.deck)
```

#### Output:

```
Please enter a number of cards to be dealt: 4
Please enter a number of players: 5

Deck:

['A♥', 'A♠', 'A♣', 'A♦', '2♥', '2♠', '2♣', '2♦', '3♥', '3♠', '3♣', '3♦', '4♥', '4♠', '4♣', '4♦', '5♥', '5♠', '5♣', '5♦', '6♥', '6♠', '6♣', '6♦', '7♥', '7♠', '7♣', '7♦', '8♥', '8♠', '8♣', '8♦', '9♥', '9♠', '9♣', '9♦', '10♥', '10♠', '10♣', '10♦', 'J♥', 'J♠', 'J♣', 'J♦', 'Q♥', 'Q♠', 'Q♣', 'Q♦', 'K♥', 'K♠', 'K♣', 'K♦']

Shuffled Deck:

['6♥', '5♠', '6♣', '8♦', '10♠', '2♣', '4♦', '6♦', 'J♦', '3♥', '8♥', 'K♥', '10♦', 'A♦', '10♣', '2♥', '3♣', '4♣', '10♥', '8♠', '9♦', '3♦', 'A♣', '9♥', 'Q♦', '5♥', 'Q♠', '9♣', 'K♦', '7♥', 'J♥', '7♠', '2♦', '7♣', 'A♠', 'J♣', '4♠', '5♣', '9♠', '7♦', '2♠', 'Q♥', 'J♠', 'A♥', '4♥', '5♦', 'K♠', '8♣', '3♠', 'Q♣', '6♠', 'K♣']

Dealt cards:

[['K♣', 'K♠', 'Q♥', '4♠'], ['6♠', '5♦', '2♠', 'J♣'], ['Q♣', '4♥', '7♦', 'A♠'], ['3♠', 'A♥', '9♠', '7♣'], ['8♣', 'J♠', '5♣', '2♦']]

Cards left in the deck after the deal:

['6♥', '5♠', '6♣', '8♦', '10♠', '2♣', '4♦', '6♦', 'J♦', '3♥', '8♥', 'K♥', '10♦', 'A♦', '10♣', '2♥', '3♣', '4♣', '10♥', '8♠', '9♦', '3♦', 'A♣', '9♥', 'Q♦', '5♥', 'Q♠', '9♣', 'K♦', '7♥', 'J♥', '7♠']
```